# How to prevent user changes the maxlength of textarea in developer tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to limit characters for textarea like in Twitter and I am using these codes for it.

But what if user changes the maxlength option in Developer Tools and raise the limit? Is there anything to prevent that rather than backend security?

I am going to get the input value with [substr](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.substr.php) function but also I want to prevent this kind of developer tools hacks. Or shouldn't I try to prevent that?

```js
var text_max = $(".textarea").attr("maxlength");
$('.character-counter').html(text_max);

$('.textarea').keyup(function() {
  var text_length = $('.textarea').val().length;
  var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

  $('.character-counter').html(text_remaining);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea" maxlength="100" col="5" rows="5"></textarea>
<p class="character-counter"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything to prevent that rather than backend security?

Nothing reasonable or that would be foolproof, no. But then, you need the backend security **anyway**, because you can't trust anything the client sends the server. They may not even be using a browser to send the data to you.

---

If you just want to make it harder for them to send you invalid information, you could do something like have a timer that resets the limits every 100ms or something like that. **It is not a substitute for backend security**, but then (again), nothing is.

Answer (score 5):

> *Is there anything to prevent that rather than backend security?*

**No, there isn't. Any/all client side code can be manipulated and bypassed.**

Use HTML and JavaScript validation on the client to assist honest users in correctly providing you with the data you want. And use server-side validation as well to guard against the hackers.