# Can i hide value?

Tags: html

I have some problem on my Bulk SMS Platform

I want to Hide this `value="test"` because when anyone visit my bulk sms website and try to edit this value name with inspect element, they write anything
Can i hide this?

```
    <label for="name">Sender</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="name" name="name"  class="form-control">
        <option value="">Choose Name</option>
        <option value="test">TEST SMS</option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: 1. This is a bad way to do it. 2. You can hide any html node with css.

Comment: If you give the user the option to pick a, b or c you'll need to make sure on the server side that the values you receive is either a, b or c and nothing else. You can never blindly trust the data that your server receives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent user changes the maxlength of textarea in developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609418/how-to-prevent-user-changes-the-maxlength-of-textarea-in-developer-tools)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not hide HTML code from a visitor. If you need to use something protected, you need to use a backend server and call the backend for the values.